# How to fetch data based on selectedSegmentIndex

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am required to fetch data based on what cell a user selects. I started having issues when I integrated segmented control. When a user selects female/male. The home UI will change based on what index is selected on the segment control. The problem I am currently having is when a user does select a cell. I'm not sure if I am using the `switch` statement correctly or not but, however not post is being fetched. I even ensured in the database that every category has a dummy photo to fetch.

Here is the code for the home page which works fine but code may be relevant to some.

**Code is edited based on answer below now**

On `didSelect` I am getting an error now that states

> Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Trend?'

I thought by adding `name` to `vc.trend` would be able to fetch the data because before we even implemented segmentedControl, `didSelect` worked fine by just using the name of a trend, then we would fetch photos based on the trend name.

```swift
       case 0: vc.trend.name = femaleTrends[indexPath.row]
        case 1: vc.trend.name = maleTrends[indexPath.row]
```

```swift
   var selectedSegmentIndex = 0
   var header: HomeViewHeaderReusableView?


// Reload data when index changes
 func handleSegControlTapped(for header: HomeViewHeaderReusableView) {
        selectedSegmentIndex = header.segmentedControl!.selectedSegmentIndex
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

   // Return the number of trend categories availabe
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        switch selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0: return femaleTrends.count
        case 1: return maleTrends.count
        default: print("opps, cant load data")
           return 0
        }

    }

    //Display the current trend image place holder and labels
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "homeViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CurrentTrendsCell

        switch selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0: cell.trendsLabel.text = femaleTrends[indexPath.row]
        cell.trendsImageView.image = femaleImages[indexPath.row]


        case 1: cell.trendsLabel.text = maleTrends[indexPath.row]
        cell.trendsImageView.image = maleImages[indexPath.row]

        default: break

        }

        return cell


    }


    // Selected HomeView Cell data will pass to second home view controller
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "selectedHomeCellView") as! SelectedCellHomeViewController

        switch selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0: vc.trend = femaleTrends[indexPath.row]
        case 1: vc.trend = maleTrends[indexPath.row]
            default: break
        }

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BackButton")
       self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: nil, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    }
```

**This is the viewController code with the issue**

```swift
   // Display uploaded photos
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
   }

   // Get a photo cell
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userPhotos", for: indexPath) as! PostCollectionViewCell

       cell.posts = posts[indexPath.item]


       return cell
   }


var trend: Trend!


func fetchPosts() {
  print("fetching post")

   self.trendDetails = trend.details
   self.trendName = trend.name

  switch trend.gender  {

      case .female:
       FEMALE_TRENDS_REF.child((trend.childValue)).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
             let postId = snapshot.key
             Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
                 self.posts.append(post)
                 self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                 return post1.creationDate > post2.creationDate
             })
             self.collectionView?.reloadData()
          })

   }


           case .male:
               MALE_TRENDS_REF.child((trend.childValue)).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
              let postId = snapshot.key
              Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
                  self.posts.append(post)
                  self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                  return post1.creationDate > post2.creationDate
              })
              self.collectionView?.reloadData()

           })


     }

}

   }
```

```swift
 let femaleTrends = [

Trend(name: "Animal Prints", details: "girl prints", image: UIImage(named: "Animal Prints"), gender: .female, childValue: "animalprints"),


Trend(name: "Dark Romance", details: "Darkromance text.",image: UIImage(named: "Dark Romance"),gender: .female, childValue: "darkromance"),


Trend(name: "Green", details: "Green text.",image: UIImage(named: "Green"),gender: .female, childValue: "green"),]




    let maleTrends = [

Trend(name: "Animal Prints", details: "mens animal prints",image:UIImage(named: "Aprint"),gender: .male , childValue: "animalprints"),


Trend(name: "Corduroy", details: "mens corduroy",image: UIImage(named: "CorduroyM"),gender: .male, childValue: "corduroy"),


Trend(name: "Earth Tones", details: "mens earth tones",image: UIImage(named: "Earth Tones"),gender: .male, childValue: "earthtones"),

]
```

I basically want to fetch data based on the trend name and segmentIndex..

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHYojHVey7s&t=3s please watch this may be it helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model is inappropriate.

You are strongly discouraged from using multiple arrays as data source.

Declare a struct which contains all information of one item in the collection view and add an enum for the gender information.

```
enum Gender { case male, female }

struct Trend {
   let name : String
   let details : ...
   let image : ...
   let gender : Gender
   // other properties 
}
```

Populate the data model accordingly.

Then pass **one** item to the detail view controller, the selected segment index is not needed.

```
switch selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0: vc.trend = femaleTrends[indexPath.row]
    case 1: vc.trend = maleTrends[indexPath.row]
    default: break
}
```

In the *view controller with the issue* declare a property

```
var trend : Trend!
```

and fetch the posts depending on the `gender` information

```
func fetchPosts() {
   print("fetching post")

   self.trendDetails = trend.details ?? ""
   self.trendName = trend.name ?? ""

   switch trend.gender  {

       case .female:
           FEMALE_TRENDS_REF.child((trend.childValue)!).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
              let postId = snapshot.key
              Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
                  self.posts.append(post)
                  self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                  return post1.creationDate > post2.creationDate
              })
              self.collectionView?.reloadData()
           })
       case .male:
           MALE_TRENDS_REF.child((trend.childValue)!).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
               let postId = snapshot.key
               Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
                   self.posts.append(post)
                   self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                   return post1.creationDate > post2.creationDate
               })
               self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and education! I am going ti edit my question to add the ```femaleTrends``` and ```maleTrends``` properties. I am having a hard time passing that data into ```didSelect``` I do not know how to assign a value of ```type 'String' to type 'Trend?'```

Comment: With the edited code this error can not occur. Please learn to understand that the entire `Trend` object is passed to be able to access and use all properties.